# Chrome hangs when I load Select2 with by default selected 3000 options

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-select2

My app basically list groups and each have group detail page(edit).
Group detail page contains Enter group name(TextField) and Select users(select2) field.

Select users input(select2) by default selects users using initSelection(ajax option) methon in select2

No of users = 3000.

PS: Select2 Version: 3.4.3

Comment: The browser is simply collapsing under the weight of the amount of data you're providing. I'd suggest you look at using an auto complete field instead

Comment: Yeah I had a similar problem and ended up switching to typeahead. It handled the large amounts of data much better.

Comment: I already have auto complete while getting/adding new users but I need to set 3000 users by default(you can consider it as edit group form page)